# C# AS3 MMO Socket Server/Client

Tags: c#, xml, actionscript-3, sockets

I'm making a micro-mmorpg as a project. I'm making the server using c#, and the client is Flash AS3. How should I organize the client-server messaging system? I want a client to be able to send a message to: all clients in room, the server, a specific client. Should I have some sort of client ID or is that already built in? Should my messages(XML) have a to/from tag? I was thinking of holding a map of movieclips in the game where the key is the clientid and the movieclip is what it points to, so that way the server can say: clientId has disconnected, and then my game can get the avatar by the clientId and remove it from the display list etc. So would this be a good way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think [Socket](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/Socket.html) is the best choice in AS3 if you need realtime. 
 also imho there's no other way to identify/authorize a client except using clientID. 
 however i know almost nothing about the game, but i think basic logic should be like:

- after the client has connected it
  sends user actions to the server
  every `timeout` seconds. if there're
  no actions it should send a default
  ping.
- when the server recieves
  data from the client it checks if
  it's not cheated and if all is ok it
  updates the current state of all
  affected entities and sends the new
  state description as an answer